# Internet connection from Philips hue bridge vie Huawei CPE 2 fails

Tags: connection, router, huawei-mobile-services, hue

I searched for a long time in the internet, found some ideas, but they refer to different routers. I can't connect my hue bridge with the internet using the Huawei CPE 2 router. I put the ethernet cable into "LAN/WAN". Is it correct? Just "LAN" didn't work (internet LED was off). Now the internet LED is blinking, the other two LED's are on.

There are many possibilities what one can switch on and off in the menu (http://192.168.8.1/html/index.html). It would be very kind if you could help me. I can put screenshots of the configuration here. UPNP is switched on, dynamic DHCP on.

Thank you very much! As attachment I send you the ethernet settings of the Huawei CPE 2 and the status (disconnected).

Best regards,
Markus

[image: Settings1]

[image: Settings2]

[image: Ethernet-Status]

Comment: Originally "Set DNS server manually" was switched off. This also doesn't work then. There is a problem to connect. But I don't know why...

Answer (score 0):

Change the MTU size of the Dynamic IP to 1300.  That then worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).